# How to fetch data before rendering using Vue 3 and the composition api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I want to fetch some data from an API an then populate my store (for example, user info) but I cannot find a way to do it *before* the entire page and components loads.

I discovered that there is a method called `beforeRouteEnter` that you can use with the options api, but what if I want to use the composition api (specifically with `<script setup>`).

I also tried this:

```
const router = useRouter()

router.beforeResolve(() => {
  // fetch api and populate store
})
```

And this:

```
router.beforeEach(() => {
  // fetch api and populate store
})
```

But none of them do what I need.

Comment: What about `beforeMount` inside the central app component?

Comment: @Nechoj I tried it in my App.vue but a component that uses the store in the setup method throws an error because the api was not fetched before it's rendering.

Comment: Strange. My app uses the vuex store and usually I pre-fetch the data. Example: `this.$store.dispatch('getPersons');` is a call to an async action in the vuex store that retrieves data from the IndexedDB and populates the data in the vuex store. And this method works inside the `beforeMount` of the component. Maybe you have a different data source?

Comment: Wait, I'm using the `onBeforeMount` hook in the `<script setup>`. Do I must use options api instead?

Comment: A yes, it makes a difference. From the docs:
`These lifecycle hook registration functions can only be used synchronously during setup(), since they rely on internal global state to locate the current active instance (the component instance whose setup() is being called right now). Calling them without a current active instance will result in an error.`
If async, better use the options API. 

I did a test and moved the call to setup and then I get this error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$store')`

Comment: @Nechoj I tried, it still not works, it loads the page and then fetch the data.

Comment: If the call is within beforeMount and the data arrives later, then it must be an asynchonous call, right?

Comment: @Nechoj Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239535/discussion-between-alex3025-and-nechoj).

Answer (score 0):

as shown in one of the related questions here:
[How to make api call within created hook in vue 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73707504/how-to-make-api-call-within-created-hook-in-vue-3)

the right way in the composition APi is to simply make a

```
<script setup>
... imports...

const pizzas = ref([])

const GetPizzas = async () => {
  await api.get('pizza/pizzas/').then((response) => {
    pizzas.value = response.data
  })
}
GetPizzas()

</script>
```

which actually makes sense, as in the compositionAPI the setup call is the "onLoad" or "onBeforeMount"