# How to make api call within created hook in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Came back to vue after long break. In my solution im using composition api where I need to fetch some data once the component is created so I can display it later on. In my current solution, template is kinda rendered before the call has been made. Probably stupid mistake but still I cannot figure it out (in vue 2.0 it was clear - created() hook).

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div class="row mb-2 border-top border-bottom" v-for="pizza in pizzas" :key="pizza">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" style="height: 100px; width: 135px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
          {{pizza.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md offset-md-2 mt-4">
          price
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 mt-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {api} from "@/api.js"

let pizzas = null

const GetPizzas = async ()=>{
    await api.get('pizza/pizzas/')
    .then(response=>{
        pizzas = response.data
    })
}
GetPizzas()
</script>
```

Comment: It was exactly the same in Vue 2 and created hook. Don't show the layout that relies on fetched data before it's fetched. You may want to check suspense otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of available hooks in Composition API is here:

- https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html

The closest thing to Options API's `created` is running the code in `setup()` function. However, to avoid having to guard the template with `v-if="pizzas"`, you should instantiate it as an empty array.

And, obviously, you want it to be reactive, so it's `ref([])`, not just `[]`.

```html
<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue'
import { api } from '@/api.js'

const pizzas = ref([])

const GetPizzas = async () => {
  await api.get('pizza/pizzas/').then((response) => {
    pizzas.value = response.data
  })
}
GetPizzas()

</script>
```

**Notes**:

- `<template>` can remain the same, since we initialise `pizzas` as empty array. If you initiate it as anything falsey, you need a `v-if="pizzas"` guard on the root wrapper element.
- `ref`s require assignment to their `.value`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work as what you want. Your api called at the moment component was created, not after component rendered cause it's not called in the *onMounted* hooks. Moreover, you should make pizzas reactive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).